# Journal with dated entries instead of chapters?

Tags: date

I'd like to use LaTeX to write a journal. It would be in most respects like a regular book, but with dated instead of numbered chapters. For example, instead of:

- Chapter 1 - Project Setup
- Chapter 2 - Beginning Experiments

I'd like:

- November 15 2020 - Project Setup
- November 16 2020 - Beginning Experiments

This does not seem like a typical setup for LaTeX and I cannot find any mention of LaTeX used in this way.

How do I go about configuring LaTeX to do this?

---

Clarifying what I am hoping to achieve. As in the question title, I'd like to have chapters in this document, but instead of numbered chapters, have dates. So, for a regular book chapter that looks like the following:

[image]

I'd like to change "Chapter 1" to say "November 15, 2020", and same for subsequent chapters. Then in the table of contents, instead of:

[image]

the numerals "1" and "2" would instead be replaced with the dates themselves.

Comment: I think you could do that with the `titlesec` package and its `\titleformat` command.

Comment: where is the problem? Write the date in the \chapter or \section argument.

Comment: A regular unnumbered chapter/section could also work. Do you also need a table of contents? If so, the following might be interesting: `\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{November 15 2020 - Project Setup}

some text

\section{November 16 2020 - Beginning Experiments}

some more text

\end{document}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've amended my question with specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starter. You'll need to customize the page headers and footers to your liking.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge}
  {{\itshape\thechapter}}
  {20pt}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [0pt]
  {\addvspace{1pc}\normalfont}
  {%
   \contentsmargin{0pt}{\itshape\thecontentslabel}\\*\bfseries
  }
 {\contentsmargin{0pt}}
 {\hfill\thecontentspage}
 [\addvspace{.5pc}]

\newcommand{\datedchapter}[2]{%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{#1}%
  \chapter{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\datedchapter{November 15, 2020}{Project Setup}

\begingroup\let\clearpage\relax % just to make a smaller picture, remove!

\datedchapter{November 16, 2020}{Beginning Experiments}

\endgroup % remove!

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks :)